# How can an ANT build file insert the version number in the generated Javadocs?

Tags: ant, version, javadoc

I use an ANT build file to build my project and also generate the JavaDocs with it. Therefore I use the "javadoc"-command from ANT. Until now I have the version number inserted directly in the .java-file with the "@version"-literal. So if I want to increase the version number I have to open every .java-file and change the number. 
Is it possible to define the version number once in the ANT file and let ANT insert this version number into the JavaDocs itself? How can you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the available options of the JavaDoc task I would use the `Header` atribute/element which allows to include HTML text defined in every generated file. The HTML text is defined in the the ANT task similar to the `doctitle` attribute:

```
<javadoc ...>
    <header><![CDATA[<p>Version: ${myversion}</p>]]></header>
</javadoc>
```

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html

Comment: I am sorry, that does not work for me. It still displays the version number of the javadoc from all the .java-files.

Comment: Then just skip the silly @version statement. Remove it or if you really want to build upon it use a script for updating all your files.